# Сандали или сандалии?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Изначально, конечно, "сандалии". Но есть ли в русском языке слово "сандали", "сандаль" или это просторечные слова, а писать все равно правильно "сандалии", "сандалия"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Сандалии** - обувь древних греков и римлян. Тут "сандали" невозможно.
**Сандалии** и (разг.) **Сандали** - современные открытые летние туфли на ремешке и без каблука. 
(по БТС Кузнецова).

Answer (score 2):

Единственное число - **сандалия**, множественное - **сандалии**. Упоминания о разговорном варианте в словарях нет, но, я думаю, большой ошибки в разговорном (устном) *сандали* нет.

Comment: Есть. У Кузнецова.

Comment: Спасибо. Будем знать.

Comment: Я про упоминание, не про ошибку. Надеюсь, что не ввел в заблуждение.

Answer (score 0):

В разговорном употреблении встречаются "сандали", "сандальки"